# Javascript styling nth child

Tags: javascript, css

I am currently applying a css class based on the sum of 2 nth childs height for example if height of 2nd child + height of 3rd child equals x add specific class.

This is my javascript to calculate -

```
$(function() {
var fl = $('ul img:nth-child(3n+3)').height();
var fr = $('ul img:nth-child(3n+4)').height();
var result = fl += fr;
if (result == 1092) {
    $('ul img:nth-child(3n+3)').addClass('style1a');
    $('ul img:nth-child(3n+4)').addClass('style1b');
}
else if (result == 2460) {
    $('ul img:nth-child(3n+3)').addClass('style2a');
    $('ul img:nth-child(3n+4)').addClass('style2b');
}
else if (result == 1776) {
    $('ul img:nth-child(3n+3)').addClass('style3a');
    $('ul img:nth-child(3n+4)').addClass('style3b');
}
});
```

This almost works perfectly, it calculates the height of THE FIRST ITERATION OF 3n+3 and 3n+4 and applies a style to all 3n+3.

However, i need to alter my javascript to calculate the height of EVERY ITERATION of 3n+3 and 3n+4 rather than just the first iteration and then apply the style.

SUM of li(3)+li(4) add style, SUM of li(6)+li(7) add style.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: don't quite understand your problem. I don't see the whole scenario here, so a simple demo may help.

Comment: Current demo - http://master.blavou.co/dev3.html - as you can see the photos dont align side by side properly as the wrong class is being applied. It is applying the style based on the first (3n+3)+(3n+4) which is why that works well. @Hopeless

Comment: "if height of 2nd child + height of 3rd child equals more than x add specific class"  From what you posted, your code is checking to see if the height of 2nd child + height of 3rd child *equals* x.

Comment: apologies, was working on an old version in my head but same principle applies

Comment: looks like applying which class depends on the height, so using the selector `nth-child` here may not help and even confusing. I guess you have to loop through all the `img` (of course such as by some step of 3), check the current img and add class appropriately. Note that this `$('ul img:nth-child(3n+3)').height()` will return `height` of the first element in the collection (collected by jQuery). So your code simply means something like **many other `img`s' styles depend on just the very first `img`**, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to handle each pair of elements separately, you will need to loop over the collection.  Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/b187z18q/

```
var $threes = $('ul img:nth-child(3n+3)');  // get the collection of all 3n+3 elements
var $fours = $('ul img:nth-child(3n+4)');   // get the collection of all 3n+4 elements

for(var i = 0; i < $fours.length; i++){
    var $three = $threes.eq(i);  // get the individual element
    var $four = $fours.eq(i);    // get the individual element

    var result = $three.height() + $four.height();

    if (result == 109) {
        $three.addClass('style1a');
        $four.addClass('style1b');
    } else if (result == 246) {
        $three.addClass('style2a');
        $four.addClass('style2b');
    } else if (result == 177) {
        $three.addClass('style3a');
        $four.addClass('style3b');
    }
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  var $threes = $('ul img:nth-child(3n+3)');
  var $fours = $('ul img:nth-child(3n+4)');

  for (var i = 0; i < $fours.length; i++) {
    var $three = $threes.eq(i);
    var $four = $fours.eq(i);

    var result = $three.height() + $four.height();
    console.log(result);
    if (result == 109) {
      $three.addClass('style1a');
      $four.addClass('style1b');
    } else if (result == 246) {
      $three.addClass('style2a');
      $four.addClass('style2b');
    } else if (result == 177) {
      $three.addClass('style3a');
      $four.addClass('style3b');
    }
  }




});
```

```css
.style1a,
.style1b {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.style2a,
.style2b {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.style3a,
.style3b {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x50" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x50" />

    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x59" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x50" />

    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x50" />

    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x50" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x50" />

    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x50" />

    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x100" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x77" />

    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x50" />

    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x146" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x100" />

    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x50" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: James your idea seems to work although I having a few problems cross-browsers. Chrome - breaks of page refresh. Safari - Not working at all. Firefox - always working - http://master.blavou.co/test-doc.html

Comment: It works perfect with my set up - http://master.blavou.co/further.html other than the refresh problem

Comment: just required $(window).load()

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a clean approach to solving this problem. First, relying on exact heights could be really buggy, since if one pixel changes, your code get thrown off. Considering using less than/greater than vs equals or settings a class on the elements. Also, you should declare your jQuery variables once. A quick refactor:

```
$(function() {
var foo = $('ul img:nth-child(3n+3)');
var bar = $('ul img:nth-child(3n+4)');

switch(foo.height() + bar.height()) {
  case == 1092: 
  // You really should avoid relying on exact heights
  // Maybe try some other method to determine style
    foo.addClass('style1a');
    bar.addClass('style1b');
    break;
  case == 2460:
    foo.addClass('style2a');
    bar.addClass('style2b');
    break;
  case == 1776:
    foo.addClass('style2a');
    bar.addClass('style3b');
    break;
}
```

Comment: While the refactoring may be beneficial, it doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: Not really sure what would I could use instead of the exact height, a little background... A user will upload a full file (500+) of images not knowing what those images are other than they will be always 800px. I could use if is great than x and less than x

Answer (score 0):

$ returns a collection of elements (even if there is only one matching element it is still put into a collection). Because $ always returns a collection, jQuery looks for properties/method of the first member of the collection if it thinks it is appropriate; jQuery.each() is what you want to use to avoid that behavior.

The first few lines of your function body should be:

```
var height;
$('ul img:nth-child(3n+3)').each(function(index, element) {
    height += element.height;
}
$('ul img:nth-child(3n+4)').each(function(index, element) {
    height += element.height;
}
```

The way you calculate your result, with = and += on the same line is odd, though this code takes care of that.